# Serial Mac OS X constantly freezes/locks/dissappears for USB to Arduino

Tags: c++, xcode, serial-port, arduino, ioctl

I have a problem with my C++ code running in [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) with both the AMSerial library as well as the generic C (ioctl, termios).

After a fresh restart, my application works well but after I "kill" the program the Serial (I think) is not released.

I have checked my open files under `/dev` and have killed the connection to serial USB from there, but my C++ still can't open the USB port.

I have narrowed this down to being a low level Mac OS X issue, regarding blocking the port indefinitely, regardless of closing it using the aforementioned libraries.

Just for context, I'm trying to send numbers through my USB port, serially to an [Arduino Duemilanove](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove) at 9600 baud. Running Serial Monitor in Arduino is perfectly fine, however, running through a C++ application it freezes up my computer, occasionally, my mouse/keyboard freeze up: requiring a hard reset.

How can this problem be fixed? It seems like Mac OS X is not USB friendly!

Comment: Possibly you might find help on AVRFreaks.net?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, answered my own question a while back!
After I connect to the Arduino, I have to include a sleep(2) to ensure the serial is actually connected.